# How to fix next in eval-like logic in Perl?

Tags: perl, eval, continue

I wrote in code

```
        my $sql = ...
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);            
        eval {
            $sth->execute;
        }
        or do {
            # die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
            addToLog("SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n");
            sleep(30);
            next mysql_recover;
        };
```

but checker swears I can't use `next` inside eval. How to rewrite otherwise?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete minimal example? Right now, you are not using `next` inside `eval`...

Comment: `eval { ... } or do { ... }`? That is a pretty funky piece of code. What could you possibly hope to achieve by writing something like that?

Comment: Note, `$sth->execute` returns `undef` for an error -- and so your `eval`-handler would trigger in that case.  If that's what you want then fine, but it can be confusing since an `eval` is mostly meant to guard against exceptions (a `die`).  An idiom is `eval { ...; 1 } or do {...};`, so the `eval` always returns success (that `1`) _unless a `die` was thrown_ (and then there is still some fine print there); so `or do` runs only if there was an exception, not on "ordinary" errors (like an `undef` from DBI...)

Comment: The `next` isn't in the eval, and there's no problem with the code you posted. For example, `perl -M5.010 -we'for ("abc") { eval { 0 } or do { next } }; say "ok"'` simply prints `ok`. You need to provide code that actually produces the error you claim you get.

Comment: What is checker?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in a scope enclosing the shown code (which isn't shown). From [next](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next)

> next LABEL
> next EXPR
> next
>
> The next command is like the continue statement in C; it starts the next iteration of the loop [...]

So the shown code should be in a [loop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Loop-Control), with the label `mysql_recover`.  Or in a block with such a label, since a [block](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Basic-BLOCKs) is a loop that executes once (but then `next` should be `last`).

However, we can't tell what is wrong without more code or the actual error message. The shown code doesn't give any hints since a `next LABEL;` is legit only to target structures that *are* subject to flow control so the mere acceptance of that statement implies that `next` is fine.

That `do` block is not a part of the `eval` so I don't know what your checker might mean.

But, if there were a `next` inside of [eval](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval), then

> `eval BLOCK` does not count as a loop, so the loop control statements `next`, `last`, or `redo` cannot be used to leave or restart the block.

---

I'd like to also comment on that `eval`.

The `$sth->execute` shown as the sole statement in the `eval` can return an `undef`, if there is an error -- and so your `eval`-handler (the `do` block) would trigger in that case.  If that's your intent then fine, but that'd be confusing since an `eval` is meant to guard against exceptions (a `die`).

A full idiom is `eval { ...; 1 } or do {...};`, so the `eval` always returns success (that `1`) *unless a `die` was thrown* . So `or do` runs only if there was an exception, not on "ordinary" errors (like an `undef` from DBI...).

Another way to handle that would be to explicitly check for errors from `$sth->execute`, what need be done anyway. (But then add that `1` as well, against an unexpected false. Why not.)

(There is still some fine print about `$@` but that would take us elsewhere)